# VBA alternative of Application.Quit Event for VB.Net for Outlook VSTO

Tags: vb.net, outlook, event-handling, outlook-addin

Is there any VBA alternative of `Application.Quit` Event for Outlook VSTO AddIn in VB.Net ? Visual Studio have a default statement for Shutdown event in Outlook VSTO template which seem to not working or I'm not sure how to make this work

```
    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Shutdown() Handles Me.Shutdown        
    End Sub
```

I found this below code in [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/application-quit-event-outlook) which is working only in VBA, But I need this event handler for Outlook Addin so that I can trigger some event before outlook close.

```
    Private Sub Application_Quit()
        MsgBox "Goodbye, " &; Application.GetNamespace("MAPI").CurrentUser
    End Sub
```

Comment: @HansPassant , Thanks for making it duplicate though the duplicate link didn't solved my problem. However knowledge always gets boost-up by reading :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Public Class ThisAddIn

    Private Sub ThisAddIn_Startup() Handles Me.Startup
        AddHandler Application.Quit, AddressOf Application_Quit
    End Sub

    Private Sub Application_Quit()
         ' Your code
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Thanks, your solution served my purpose very nicely.